# Why did the studio make two versions of this scene?

Tags: seirei-tsukai-no-blade-dance

In *Bladedance of Elementalers*, there is a scene where Kamito's girlfriends get jealous and feed him cakes violently. What's surprising is there are 2 versions of this scene:

1. His girlfriends use sticks to [feed him](https://youtu.be/thgTSmS2tmY?t=583).
   [image]
2. His girlfriends push the plate [against his face](https://youtu.be/nf0CJbxIRN0?t=165).
   [image]

Why did the studio make two versions of this? It's quite rare that a studio would bother to do extra work, since one version is enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**This was possibly a scene correction done for the DVD & BD release.**

The scene happened near the end of episode 12, "*Ren Ashbell*". Cross-checking the reviews reveals that the scene with "cake-shoving" was initially broadcasted on TV, on September 30, 2014.

- http://tiwaha.cocolog-nifty.com/blog/2014/09/tokyomx92912-b4.html (Japanese, September 30, 2014, TokyoMX)

  > 私のケーキを食べてとカミトの顔面に押し付けるフィアナ、リンスレット、トドメはエストだった。
  >
  > "Eat my cake", said Fianna, Rinslet, and Est while shoving the cake onto Kamito's face.
- https://ameblo.jp/cm118466081/entry-11932644894.html (Japanese, October 1, 2014)

  > エリスのドレスが似合ってると褒めたカミトに詰め寄る他3人(爆)
  > それはケーキ食わせるじゃなくてパイ投げもとい、ケーキ投げやん！
  >
  > The other 3 girls crowded around Kamito after he compliments Ellis' dress
  > That's not feeding the cake, that's pie-throwing, or rather cake-shoving!
- http://yaraon-blog.com/archives/58516 (Japanese, 30 September 2014) showing the archive of 2ch thread, with screencaps from episodes 12 added, including the cake-shoving.

However, *the scene is actually different from the original source (light novel) where the girls are forcing Kamito to eat the cake using forks instead of shoving it*, and it disappointed some Japanese fans.

- http://yaraon-blog.com/archives/58516 (Japanese). From one of the comments on the article,

  > 20. 名前：名無しさん 投稿日：2014-09-30 01:42:00
  >     てか、ケーキのシーンは原作通り全員フォークでカミトの口に入れてあげろよ…
  >     何であんな雑で、しかも印象悪くするようなことした
  >
  > 20. Name: Anonymous　Posting date: 2014-09-30 01:42:00 (JST)
  >     I mean, the cake scene should be like the original source, everyone should use a fork to put it in Kamito's mouth...
  >     Why did they do it so rough, moreover it makes a bad impression
- https://sakuhindb.com/janime/7_Seireitsukai_20no_20bladedance/2014-11-02T14_33_50.html (Japanese).

  > 【悪い点】
  > [...]
  > 最終回でチョコレートケーキをカミトの顔にぶつけるシーン。食いモンを粗末にするんじゃねえ。もしこれが「ドリフのコントみたいでおもろいやろ?」とか思ってやってるんだとしたら救えない
  >
  > Bad Points
  >
  > The scene where chocolate cakes are shoved onto Kamito's face in the last episode. Don't waste food. If this was done with the reasoning "this should be interesting like [*Dorifu*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Drifters_(Japanese_band))'s skit", then it is beyond saving.